# LevelDB TEST_ Prefix for Methods

Tags: c++, leveldb

I'm reading through the code in LevelDB and I keep running across a TEST_ prefix that's used. I would expect that TEST_ indicates that this method is used for tests to be able to operate on internals that wouldn't otherwise be public. As such, I'd expect that none of this would be in any critical paths. I'd expect them to be in none of the primary methods. However, TEST_CompactRange for example is called from CompactRange which is apart of the main compaction path. What does this TEST_ prefix mean, and where can I find this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors seem to use the `TEST_` prefix for public methods that are not intended to be part of the API. The methods are public only to make testing easier, and they are prefixed with `TEST_` to discourage users from calling them.

Why shouldn't these methods appear in critical paths? They are like private methods, but visible for testing.

Other thoughts:

- I'm not sure whether this naming convention is a best practice. C++ has [friend declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) that could accomplish something similar.
- The naming convention is similar to the Java Guava library's `@VisibleForTesting` annotation

Edit: To be clear, I'm just making a guess based on the handful of methods with the `TEST_` prefix. Grepping the codebase shows that the only such methods are the following (all public):

```
// Compact any files in the named level that overlap [*begin,*end]
void TEST_CompactRange(int level, const Slice* begin, const Slice* end);

// Force current memtable contents to be compacted.
Status TEST_CompactMemTable();

// Return an internal iterator over the current state of the database.
// The keys of this iterator are internal keys (see format.h).
// The returned iterator should be deleted when no longer needed.
Iterator* TEST_NewInternalIterator();

// Return the maximum overlapping data (in bytes) at next level for any
// file at a level >= 1.
int64_t TEST_MaxNextLevelOverlappingBytes();
```